# Dynamic SQL for null parameter

Tags: dynamic-sql

I'm creating records in table TELPOOL with columns:

- POOLID, varchar
- POOLNAME, varchar
- POOLTYPE, varchar
- PAIRPOOLID, varchar

If poolPO.pairPoolID is null, insert like this

```sql
INSERT INTO TELPOOL (POOLID, POOLNAME, POOLTYPE)
     VALUES (#{poolPO.id}, #{poolPO.name}, #{poolPO.poolType}
```

Otherwise,

```sql
INSERT INTO TELPOOL (POOLID, POOLNAME, POOLTYPE, PAIRPOOLID)
     VALUES (#{poolPO.id}, #{poolPO.name}, #{poolPO.poolType}, #{poolPO.pairPoolID})
```

How can I handle the two situactions by a single dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution by using MyBatis  condition. There are still two SQLs in mapper XML, but upper layer code needn't any change.

```sql
<insert id="createTelPool" flushCache="true" >
    <if test="poolPO.pairPoolID != null" >
        INSERT INTO WBXTELPOOL (POOLID, POOLNAME, POOLTYPE, PAIRPOOLID)
             VALUES (#{poolPO.id}, #{poolPO.name}, #{poolPO.poolType}, #{poolPO.pairPoolID})
    </if>
    <if test="poolPO.pairPoolID == null" >
        INSERT INTO WBXTELPOOL (POOLID, POOLNAME, POOLTYPE)
             VALUES (#{poolPO.id}, #{poolPO.name}, #{poolPO.poolType})
    </if>
</insert>
```